# Can I Bulky this further?

Tags: trigger, bulkification

Is there any way to bulkify this more?
Here is the code

```
trigger CreateCampaignMemberBulkify on Contact (after insert,after update) {

    // Creating a container
    List<CampaignMember> allCM = new List <CampaignMember>();

    // Single instance of a contact from list contacts to insert or update 
    for(Contact c:Trigger.new)
    {
        // Make sure the custom campaign field has a value 
        if(c.Campaign__c != null)
        {
            //Check for dupe based on current campaign and current contact
            List<CampaignMember> cml=[select ID from CampaignMember where Campaign.Id=:c.Campaign__c and Contact.Id=:c.Id];
            if(cml.size()==0)
            {
               // Create new campaign member with campaign id and contact id
               CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember();
               cm.CampaignId=c.Campaign__c;
               cm.ContactId=c.Id;

               // Adding new campaign members to campaign member list
               allCM.add(cm);

            }
        }
    }
    // Inserting list of campaign members into database
    Database.insert (allCM);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

100%. Currently you have a SOQL query inside a for loop. You should never ever do that for whatever reason. Instead you can utilise collections that are available in apex which allow you to avoid that (list, set, map). [Read this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Avoid_SOQL_Queries_Inside_FOR_Loops) for more info on how to avoid this problem.

Here is a quick re-write of your current code that should help you get started and understand how to approach these situations:

```
List<CampaignMember> allCM = new List <CampaignMember>();
// Set of all contact IDs in the trigger
Set <Id> contactIds = new Set <Id> ();
// Set of all campaign IDs in the trigger (from the contact lookup)
Set <Id> campaignIds = new Set <Id> ();
// Map of composite key (contactID + campaignID) and matching Campaign Member in the system (existing)
Map <String, CampaignMember> contactIdToCampaignMember = new Map <String, CampaignMember> (); 

// Find all the targeted contact and camapign IDs
for (Contact c : trigger.new)
{
    if (c.Campaign__c != null)
    {
        contactIds.add(c.Id);
        campaginIds.add(c.Campaign__c);
    }
}

// Query the existing campaign members and populate the map (1 query)
for(CampaignMember existingCm : [select ID, ContactId, CampaignId from CampaignMember where CampaignId IN :campaginIds and ContactId IN :contactIds])
{
    contactIdToCampaignMember.put('' + existingCm.ContactId + existingCm.CampaignId, existingCm);
}

// Loop again through the contacts in the trigger
for (Contact c : trigger.new)
{
    // For the ones that there are no matching campaign members based on the composite key, create new CM
    if (c.Campaign__c != null && contactIdToCampaignMember.get('' + c.Id + c.Campaign__c) == null)
    {
        // Create new campaign member with campaign id and contact id
        CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember();
        cm.CampaignId = c.Campaign__c;
        cm.ContactId = c.Id;

        // Adding new campaign members to campaign member list
        allCM.add(cm);
    }
}

// Inserting list of campaign members into database
Database.insert (allCM);
```

Please note that this is written in a text editor and never compiled. There might be some typos but you should be able to get the idea.

Comment: Nice code. But is there any concern on the 15 or 18 digits of Ids which makes them not match?

Comment: In both cases here the references are made to an Id and not a String. In the case where a single Id is stored in a String, you can always cast back to Id.

Comment: I agree. But the key of your map is the combination of two Ids which can't cast back. I am just wondering whether it is necessary to do a bit walking around on this before combining them into a string.

Comment: When I put them into the string they always come from an Id, so the result will be the same. Alternatively you can substring them all and work with the 15 characters ones

Comment: You could also write a dual id class to use as your key if you're really worried.